# Firebase Messaging Critical Sound

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have sent notification with firebase messaging. I want to create critical alert IOS notification but i can not found true body for firebase api. I tried many bodies like:

```
 "apns": {
      "headers": {
        "apns-priority": "5"
      },
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
             "sound":  {
            "name": "alert.mp3",
            "volume": 1,
            "critical": true
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

and notification {

```
"sound":  {
    "name": "alert.mp3",
    "volume": 1.0,
    "critical": 1 // and true
  },
}
```

I have permission for critical alert from IOS and I create profile for IOS.  However, I can not create critical alert.

I want to find true body for Firebase Messaging Critical Alert.I tried this codes from postman with https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send. I can not find solution.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue, I have resolved using following approach, I hope it will work for you as well:

```
Notification = new FirebaseAdmin.Messaging.Notification()
            {
                Title = "Test Message",
                Body = "You have a new Test message!"
            },
            Token = "your-device-token",
            //sound configurations for android
            Android = new AndroidConfig()
            {
                Notification = new AndroidNotification()
                {
                    Sound = "default", 
                    DefaultVibration = true,
                    Priority = Priority.High, 
                    Visibility = Visibility.Public, 
                    NotificationPriority=AndroidNotificationPriority.High, 
                   Category = "alarm", 
                   Color = "#FF0000", 
                   CriticalSound = new CriticalSound()
                  {
                    Name = "my_critical_sound", // Set the name of the critical sound
                    Volume = 1.0, // Set the volume of the critical sound (0.0 - 1.0)
                  },
                },
            },
            //sound configuration for ios
            Apns = new ApnsConfig()
            {
                Aps = new Aps()
                {
                    Sound = "default",
                },
            },
```

Note: I am using .NET 6, and to implement above approach, a nuget package is required **FirebaseAdmin**, which contains required classes. For more details please refer to official documentation of firebase.

[Link to Official Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/dotnet/class/firebase-admin/messaging/critical-sound)

I hope this will help to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem as well and after some experimenting and reading through Apple's documentation found out that the missing part is a also to specify `interruption-level: critical` in `payload` dictionary. Also `sound` dictionary should be outside `aps`, just in `payload`.

With that said here is an example body to send a critical message based on your example:

```
"apns": {
      "payload": {
        "aps": {
          "interruption-level": "critical",
        }
        "sound": {
            "name": "alert.mp3",
            "volume": 1.0,
            "critical": 1
        }
      }
    },
```

Here is the official APNs dictionary documentation with all possible options for a reference:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification#2943360

UPD: In fact, I was able to get alerts as critical, but had no luck with setting the sound that I want. Tried multiple different variations of config and had all sounds added into the iSO project, but had no luck. In the end switched to another push notifications provider where specifying the sound name in the API request actually makes the app play the correct sound.

Comment: Thank you for posting this.. I'm going to try this solution now. I've been trying to get this to work for the last 2 weeks and the firebase documentation is hard to find. I really would like to stick to using FCM

Comment: Is the above example what you used? I tried using that format and I'm met with:
"FirebaseMessagingError: Messaging payload contains an invalid "apns" property. Valid properties are "data" and "notification" in my log.

Comment: If you are trying to send via https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send it won't work, because legacy API doesn't support these customisations and you need to use HTTP V1 API instead. I was also having troubles with legacy API till saw in another StackOverflow question that legacy API won't allow to specify platform specific properties.

Comment: I had no idea. I will have to convert my function to use HTTP V1 API. You never had any luck with using a custom sound for critical? My users have a set of sounds they can choose from for push notifications I was hoping to keep that with the critical alert functionality

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, had no luck with custom sound. Wasted a few hours and moved on to another push provider, because the project where I need this functionality is something that is needed urgent, so I don't have much time finding out what else Firebase forgot to add into their docs.

Comment: Hey so just in case you want to try FCM again I was successfully able to use custom sounds with the same formatting you used however... I'm unable to get the volume property to work.